# Addin button in module with same name: "The macro may not be available in this workbook"

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a custom addin with buttons. I made a simple one for "Center Across".

I created the Addin using OfficeRibbonXEditor-NET5-Binaries and the module is called CenterAcross.

I get

> "The macro may not be available in this workbook"

```vb
Sub CenterAcross(control As IRibbonControl)

    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: How did you create the button, and what is the name of the module that code is in?

Comment: So I created a Addon using OfficeRibbonXEditor-NET5-Binaries and the module is called CenterAcross. (same name as the actual macro).

Comment: Change the module name to something else.

Comment: OMW I didnt even think of that, thank you Rory, that worked perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this as what Rory mentioned and it worked. Changed the module name.